# Use Maven's EventSpyDispatcher in a custom Junit RunListener

Tags: java, maven, maven-surefire-plugin, plexus

I'm trying to write a custom Junit `RunListener`, to be called by Surefire when executing tests.
My listener should create some custom 'events' to be sent through Maven's `EventSpyDispatcher`, so that these can get picked up by an event spy that I also created.

My `CustomTestRunListener` lives in a separate jar that is added to the test scope classpath of Surefire.
My listener looks like this

```
@Component(role = RunListener.class)
public class CustomTestRunListener extends RunListener {

    @Requirement
    EventSpyDispatcher eventSpyDispatcher;

    public CustomTestRunListener() {
        System.out.println("CustomTestRunListener created");
        System.out.println(eventSpyDispatcher);
    }

    @Override
    public void testRunStarted(Description description) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("testRunStarted");
    }
}
```

It it wired successfully in Surefire, because I can see my `System.out` statements being printed.

But the eventSpyDispatcher is not injected (the sytem out on it is 'null')
How can I achieve this ?